# Who is responsible to purchase 3rd party tools/licenses?

Tags: freelancing, software, consultants, consulting

I have a question. I'm a contractor working for a sw development company (let's call it "ABC Dev"). They are outsourcing me to other companies to do .net development. One of these client projects require the purchase of a 3rd party control, which costs several hundred dollars. As a contractor, am I responsible for this cost? Or is the company I'm "working for", ABC Dev, responsible?

Comment: If I'm an employee of a company, they have ALWAYS provided me with all the tools I need, machine, ide and other software (visual studio included), and others like headphones.  As a contractor, I have only ever been provided a temporary use of an ide license that IS NOT mine should I or my employer terminate the contract.  As a 1099'er, you should assume that you should purchase everything.  Would you contract out to  a business that didn't buy the proper tools to complete their job?  What would you say to a graphic design shop that said they couldn't afford photoshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the details of the contracts involved. In the final analysis the client should be paying for it, but in they may try to pass that cost back to the contractor in some way. The common structures I've seen for your situation are that you're sent in as a suit and the client provides everything from the office space down to the web browser you use (and you may be a "named resource" or a generic "body" - ie, the client is getting you specifically or just a .net developer); the client is providing office space and the contractor provides everything else (hosted contract). Knowing exactly what's being paid for would make it much easier to work out what is happening.

Often the contract is set up so that they never see the detailed costs directly, it's built into the overall contract or daily rate they pay for devs.

In your case it also depends on what exactly you're providing to ABCDev - if they've hired you as "dotnet programmer: one, with tools" then they can quite reasonably expect you to be a programmer with tools and have negotiated a rate that reflects that. If it's more of a labour hire contract where you turn up and they provide the tools... then they provide the tools.

Similarly, if ABCDev is selling you to the client as just a monkey in a suit, then the client will be providing the tools, offices, coffee and so on. This is very common, and it may well be you. If you're working on the customer site using a computer they provide, then I'd expect them to also provide the software you need. If they're providing the Visual Studio license, why not the Tool'O'Matic license too?

**I think your best bet is to ask**, and if they are changing the requirements, push back a bit. If you're being asked to buy just this one specific tool, ask why, and ask where in your contract it says that they can ask you to do that.

Then re-negotiate the rate because you hadn't realised they were going to do interpret that clause in that way. I'd have no shame asking them to add the tool cost to my weekly rate, to give you an idea of the scale of fee you should be asking. Especially because if they do this once they're likely to do it again. You may be better off just walking away, since in the end you might find yourself pushed into the "provides everything" down to office space end of the market (so find out what those rates are now, and ask for that rate now if that's where this is going)

Answer (score 0):

Those companies - ABCDev, that act as outsourcing companies (in effect, recruiters with a pool of <s>slaves</s> programmers)? They are the worst. Just leave them and do work elsewhere.

As to your dilemma, yes, you should ask ABCDev to get you the software, and then ABCDev can bill ClientCorp for the cost.

A word of warning: no one is "supposed to" or "is responsible" here, in the sense you don't have any legal standing here. So bring it up politely and respectfully with your HR-or-whatever-contact at ABCDev.

So ABCDev can say no, but that would be a mean thing to do and only something a <s>slaveowner</s> company you don't want to work for would do.